# Create a table with a name taken from a variable in php and append a string to it

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table with the name taken from a variable in php.
The table name also would need to be appended with a string.
For example, $ProjectID is taking an input from an html form.
I would need to create different tables for different iterations of the project review.
So, when the project is submitted for the first time and if the project ID is 12345, a table needs to be created as P12345-1st-Review or P12345_1st_Review.
How do I do that?
I am able to create the table with the input from $ProjectID, but I am not able to append 1st_Review to it.
Any help?
The code that I have used is as below:

```
$ProjectID=$_POST['ProjectID'];

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $PID._1st_review (No int(4) primary key auto_increment, findings longtext);";

mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
if (mysqli_error($dbconnect))
{
    ECHO "Error Description:".mysqli_error($dbconnect);
}
```

Comment: If you need to create a new Table for each new project, you are probably doing something wrong. That's not how Tables are supposed to work.

Comment: `$PID._1st_review` , is there an actual variable `$PID`? or its only a typo here? so  it should be like this `$ProjectID._1st_review`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do:

```
$ProjectID = $_POST['ProjectID'];
$ProjectID.= "_1st_review";
```

Then perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
Although I'm not sure if your query is correct(the No int thing seems vague)

```
<?php

$ProjectID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ProjectID']); //Make sure to escape this

$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ProjectID."_1st_review (No int(4) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, findings longtext);";

mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
if (mysqli_error($dbconnect))
{
    echo "Error Description:".mysqli_error($dbconnect);
}
?>
```